# Django group by month and year doesnt work

Tags: python, django, group-by

I've already read this [Django: Group by date (day, month, year)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746014/django-group-by-date-day-month-year) and all related stuff by googling "django group by month"

If I try the "cleanest" solution - using Django 1.11, I end up with this:

```
class Request(BaseModel):
    date_creation = models.DateTimeField(default=None,
                                         blank=True, null=True)

print([v for v in
       Request.objects.annotate(month=ExtractMonth('date_creation'),
                                year=ExtractYear('date_creation'),)
                      .values('month', 'year')
                      .annotate(total=Count('month'))
                      .values('month', 'year', 'total')
       ])
```

And the result doesn't do a group by! I get this:

```
[{'month': 6, 'year': 2017, 'total': 1}, 
 {'month': 7, 'year': 2017, 'total': 1}, 
 {'month': 7, 'year': 2017, 'total': 1}]
```

I need to get:

```
[{'month': 6, 'year': 2017, 'total': 1}, 
 {'month': 7, 'year': 2017, 'total': 2}]
```

I've also tried:

```
print([v for v in
       Request.objects.extra({'month': 'strftime("%m", date_creation)',
                              'year': 'strftime("%Y", date_creation)'})
                      .values('month', 'year')
                      .annotate(total=Count('*'))
                      .values('month', 'year', 'total')
       ])
```

And then I get:

```
[{'month': '06', 'year': '2017', 'total': 1},
 {'month': '07', 'year': '2017', 'total': 1},
 {'month': '07', 'year': '2017', 'total': 1}]
```

Any idead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the problem thanks to PyCharm. I seriously dont know how I could have found the solution without that IDE. The more I'm using it the more I find it powerful. Then I found the solution thanks to this: [How can I remove Model Meta ordering in Django or get the original queryset from the built in Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606959/how-can-i-remove-model-meta-ordering-in-django-or-get-the-original-queryset-from)

My `Request` model has a parent which has a field `date_creation` and a `class Meta:` with `ordering = ['date_creation']`.

So if you don't add `order_by('field_xx')` in your query, then Django *automagically* add this: `order_by('date_creation')`.

Thus my query looked like:

```
SELECT
    (strftime("%m", date_creation)) AS "month",
    (strftime("%Y", date_creation)) AS "year",
    COUNT(*) AS "total" FROM "app_request"
  GROUP BY
    (strftime("%m", date_creation)),
    (strftime("%Y", date_creation)),
    "app_request"."date_creation"
```

And it broke the query.

The solution was:

```
from django.db.models.functions.datetime import ExtractMonth, ExtractYear
print([v for v in
       Request.objects.annotate(month=ExtractMonth('date_creation'),
                                year=ExtractYear('date_creation'),)
                      .order_by()
                      .values('month', 'year')
                      .annotate(total=Count('*'))
                      .values('month', 'year', 'total')
       ])
```

Actually, my solution was working from the very beginning!

Comment: I had the same issue. My queryset was 
`SomeClass.objects.annotate(month=ExtractMonth('created_at')).values('month').annotate(users=Count('id'))`
So by looking at your answer, I edited my queryset like this
`SomeClass.objects.annotate(month=ExtractMonth('created_at')).values('month').annotate(users=Count('id')).order_by('created_at__month')`

For me the order_by('created_at__month') after the last annotate worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is what one of my queries looks like for grouping by hour:

```
MyDateObject.objects.filter(**kwargs)\
                    .extra({ "hour": "date_part('hour', timestamp AT TIME ZONE '%s')" % (ctz.zone) })\
                    .values("hour")\
                    .annotate(Count("transaction", distinct=True))
```

The difference between mine and yours is I'm using the `extra` function. I would imagine you would have to do something similar instead of your first `annotate` like this:

```
Request.objects.extra({ "month": ExtractMonth('date_creation'),
                        "year": ExtractYear('date_creation') })
               .values('month', 'year')
               .annotate(total=Count('month'))
               .values('month', 'year', 'total')
```

Note: I'm using Django 1.9.

**edit**: The more I look at this, maybe it's the `distinct=True` in my count that really makes it work.

Comment: If I try your solution, I get an error: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such function: F`. The query that is tried is `SELECT (ExtractMonth(F(date_creation))) AS "month", (ExtractYear(F(date_creation))) AS "year", COUNT(*) AS "total" FROM "app_request" GROUP BY (ExtractMonth(F(date_creation))), (ExtractYear(F(date_creation))), "app_request"."date_v_debut" ORDER BY "app_request"."date_v_debut" ASC`

Comment: I've updated my question. My latest query is very close to yours.